# How to restyle selectInput dropdown on mouse hover?

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

How to style the following items using css inside selectInput dropdown?

- list name (**not element name**, ex. *New England* in the example below)
- hover state of element in the dropdown list
- scrollbar

Please see the minimal reproducible example below.

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = basicPage(
    selectInput("state", "State", split(state.name, state.division))
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {}
)
```

Comment: Have you read the docs? https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shiny customize selectInput/selectizeInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52824678/shiny-customize-selectinput-selectizeinput)

Comment: @heds1 I have read the article, but I am not a css expert and I cannot find the correct selector to style. For example, how to change the color and background of the element when you hover over an element of the dropdown list.

Comment: @ismirsehregal thanks for your comment, but I am looking for css style on the element when you hover over the dropdown list.

Comment: Are you familiar with your browser's inspect element tools? e.g., right click on the element, click "inspect element" or whatever the context menu is in your browser, and it will pop up on the right. You can then right click on the element and choose "copy CSS selector" or something similar so see which element you need to write css for.

Comment: @heds1 yes, I am familiar with the inspect element, but I cannot find the three items I mentioned above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to style the selected option, the available options, and the option groups headers:

```
library(shiny)

css <- "
.selectize-item {
  color: blue;
}
.selectize-option {
  color: red;
}
.selectize-option:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.selectize-oheader {
  color: green !important;
  font-size: 18px !important;
}
"

render <- I("
{
  item: function(item, escape) { 
    return '<div class=\"item selectize-item\">' + escape(item.label) + '</div>'; 
  },
  option: function(item, escape) {
    return '<div class=\"option selectize-option\">' + escape(item.label) + '</div>';
  },
  optgroup_header: function(item, escape) {
    return '<div class=\"optgroup-header selectize-oheader\">' + escape(item.label) + '</div>';
  }
}")


shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML(css))),
    selectizeInput("state", "Choose a state:",
                list(`East Coast` = list("NY", "NJ", "CT"),
                     `West Coast` = list("WA", "OR", "CA"),
                     `Midwest` = list("MN", "WI", "IA")),
                options = list(render = render)
    ),
    textOutput("result")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$result <- renderText({
      paste("You chose", input$state)
    })
  }
)
```

---

## EDIT

And here is how to style the scrollbar as well:

```
css <- "
/* selected option */
.selectize-item {
  color: blue;
}
/* options */
.selectize-option {
  color: red;
}
.selectize-option:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
/* option groups headers */
.selectize-oheader {
  color: green !important;
  font-size: 18px !important;
}
/* scrollbar */
.selectize-dropdown-content::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
.selectize-dropdown-content::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
.selectize-dropdown-content::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  background-color: #D62929;
}
"
```

See [here](https://css-tricks.com/the-current-state-of-styling-scrollbars/) for different styles.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there a way to style the scrollbar as well?